# How can I find photos that are not in an album with Google photos

Tags: search, photos, google-photos

I use the Photos app from Google (photos.google.com).

When I organize my photos into albums, I often lose track of which photos I have already added to an album and which are still 'unassigned'.

Search capabilities within photos.google.com are limited. For example "in:album" analogous to "in:label" of GMail is not available.

My attempts to answer this using Google search have been unsuccessful.

How can I find the photos that have not yet been added to an album?